# How Do I Add Multiple Objects Inside A Foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

How do I make my Django view create an author model as an instance, and then save multiple objects inside the foreign key?

I have tried making a author instance, and then setting the tiktok attribute of the author instance to a new tiktok model instance with the desc, likes, etc.
This just updated the previous value, not appending a new tiktok object.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class TikTok(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, null=True)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    likes = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, max_length=100)
    shares = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, max_length=100)
    comments = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, max_length=100)
    plays = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, max_length=100)
    videoUrl = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
    videoImg = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
    music = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.desc

class Author(models.Model):
    userhandle = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    followers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tiktoks = models.ForeignKey(TikTok, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userhandle
```

And then create the instances in my views.

I want one author model, and many tiktoks associated with it.

This is what the output should look like:

```
{
   id: 1,
   userhandle: 'user'
   email: 'user@gmail.com'
   verified: True
   tiktoks: [
      #multiple arrays of tiktoks
      {
         desc: 'desc1',
         likes: 40,
         ...
      }, 
      {
         desc: 'desc2',
         likes: 40,
         ...
      }
      ...
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'd change the tiktok field to this, or similar
`tiktoks = models.ManyToManyField(TikTok)`

##### Super Basic View Using Form

```py
def create_tiktok(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        authorObj = Author.objects.filter(pk=request.POST.get('pk')).first()
        if authorObj:
            form = TikTokForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                o = form.save()
                authorObj.tiktoks.add(o)
```

#### Example Remove

```py
# format: model.field.action(obj)

authorObj.tiktoks.remove(TikTok.objects.get(pk=1))
```

#### Example Usage

```
authorObj = Author.objects.get(userhandle='Nealium')

# Looping through all
for i in authorObj.tiktoks.all():
    print(i) # <TikTok Object>

# Fetching a specific
authorObj.tiktoks.filter(slug='test').first()


# Mass Adding
tiktokList = TikTok.objects.filter(slug__icontains='te')
authorObj.tiktoks.add(*tiktokList)


# Mass Remove
authorObj.tiktoks.add(*tiktokList)


# Clear entire field
authorObj.tiktoks.clear()
```

Comment: Thank you, although this hasn't been working for me. I get the nested list and the author data, but the tiktoks field just shows one tiktok and all the values are null. What happened? I just want to create an instance of an author and save 3 tiktoks in its fk. Would tiktok_set be an alternative?

Comment: Nevermind. Thank you! I just realized my nested serializer was not set to many=True. Could you explain why I needed to use a manytomany instead of a onetomany relationship?

Comment: umm... shoot, I completely forgot about One-To-Many. maybe a post has multiple authors?- Lol. My recommendation is if there's not multiple, just change it to One-To-Many.. more than likely all my code will work the same

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by 3 ways

1. Make TikTok field many to many
2. Make Outer table to store the author and the tiktok FK
3. Make tiktok field string and store the IDs like this `1,2,3`

Comment: How do you do incorporate this in a django view? Where I can then add tiktoks (3) to a specific author instance? Could you show an example of the first? Thanks :)